# Align Android activity

Tags: android, android-activity

Is there any possibility in Android to align a dialog Activity (activity with a dialog theme) at the bottom? By default, it is displayed in the middle of the screen. I haven't found any information on that... Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not exactly what you are doing, but I had a similar problem where I needed to display a dialog from an activity - at the bottom of the screen.  The trick was to use `WindowManager.LayoutParams`.  Here's what my `onPrepareDialog` looks like:

```
public void onPrepareDialog(int dialog, Dialog dlg) {
    Window window = dlg.getWindow();
    WindowManager.LayoutParams wlp = window.getAttributes();
    switch (dialog) {
    case DIALOGUE_LOADING_PLEASE_WAIT:
        wlp.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
        window.setAttributes(wlp);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It perfectly works! And I guess this is true for any kind of activity or dialog.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't tried but searching on google found this...does this help you **[getWindow().setAttributes()](http://markmail.org/message/oftefu6wqkvisrbi)**  , I hope this will help you.

**content of the link (if it doesn't work) :-**

You can call getWindow().getAttributes() to retrieve the
WindowManager.LayoutParams for the window.  This has the following
fields involving window placement:

http://code.google.com/android/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#width

http://code.google.com/android/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#height

http://code.google.com/android/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#gravity

http://code.google.com/android/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#x

http://code.google.com/android/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#y

After making your desired changes, use getWindow().setAttributes() to
install the new values.

Note that, though you can force a specific size through the width and
height fields, in general the correct way to do this is let the window
do its normal layout and determine the window size automatically that
way.  If you have a single view in the dialog that wants a fixed size
such as 300x200, implement View.onMeasure() to call
setMeasuredDimension(300, 200).  Then when the view hierarchy layout
happens, the dialog window will be given a size that ensures your view
is that dimension (probably making the actual window larger to take
into account the dialog frame and decoration).

http://code.google.com/android/reference/android/view/View.html#onMeasure(int,%20int)